# how to fix body in y angle zero in box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am doing one game. in that moving boy sprite with body created. the boy body when move front side or back side  that will falling down.

How fix the body y axis 0?

```
    CCSprite *boySprite=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"object_boy.png"];
    boySprite.position=ccp(100,50);

    b2BodyDef boyBodyDef;
    boyBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    boyBodyDef.linearDamping = 1;
    boyBodyDef.angularDamping = 1;
    boyBodyDef.position.Set(25.0f/PTM_RATIO,(150)/PTM_RATIO);
    boyBodyDef.angle=0;
    boyBodyDef.userData = _boy;
    boyBody = world->CreateBody(&boyBodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape boyBox;
    b2FixtureDef boyBoxDef;
    boyBoxDef.shape = &boyBox;
    boyBoxDef.density = 0.5F;
    boyBox.SetAsBox(11.0f/PTM_RATIO, 30.0f/PTM_RATIO);
    boyFixture = boyBody->CreateFixture(&boyBoxDef);


    [self addChild:boySprite z:1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set fixedRotation in b2BodyDef to true.

```
 boyBodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
```